# Concatenating audio files and superimposing over video

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, moviepy

I'm trying to write a program that takes a bunch of videos from a folder, compiles them, and then takes another bunch of audio files from a folder and concatenates them to then overlay the combined audio on top of the final video (hope that makes sense). I'm able to process the videos into one final output video, but I keep running into trouble combining the audio. Below I've provided two small sections of code pertaining to audio comp, I'm using moviepy to process the videos and attempting to use it for audio as well.

```
songDirectory = './songs/'
songList = []
songs = []
audioclip=''

def makeCompilation():
    for filename in os.listdir(songDirectory):
        f = os.path.join(songDirectory, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(f) and filename.endswith(".mp3"):
            audioclip = moviepy.editor.AudioFileClip(f)
            songList.append(filename)


    for song in os.listdir(songDirectory):
        c = os.path.join(songDirectory, song)
    audio_clips = moviepy.editor.AudioFileClip(c)
    audio_output = moviepy.editor.concatenate_audioclips(audio_clips)
    finalClip = concatenate_videoclips(videos, method="compose")
    final_duration = finalClip.duration    
    final_audio_output = audio_output.set_duration(final_duration)
    final_output= finalClip.set_audio(final_audio_output).fx(afx.audio_fadein, 3.0)


    audio_path = "./songs/tempaudiofile.m4a"

    #print(description)
    # Create compilation
    final_output.write_videofile(outputFile, threads=8, temp_audiofile=audio_path, remove_temp=True, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")

    return description
```

The program appeared to be able to find the audio directory, but I needed to be able to use  os.path.join(songDirectory, filename) to point directly to each mp3 file so I messed around with it until I got the above code. And when I attempted to iterate through songList, I, as expected, got an error saying that 'str' wasn't iterable, and other errors saying that 'str' has no attribute 'duration'. Essentially, all I need it to do is iterate though the input folder and combine the files by whatever means. Code currently returns the output:

```
Free Fredobagz x Aflacko x Flint type beat - 'Default_Dance' [prod. kah]-jro0v6ogZ0Y.mp4
225.05
Total Length: 225.05
225.05
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daddyK/Desktop/comp_ bot/make_compilation3.py", line 127, in <module>
makeCompilation(path = "./videos/",
  File "/Users/daddyK/Desktop/comp_ bot/make_compilation3.py", line 110, in makeCompilation
audio_output = moviepy.editor.concatenate_audioclips(audio_clips)
  File "/Users/daddyK/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 315, in concatenate_audioclips
durations = [c.duration for c in clips]
TypeError: 'AudioFileClip' object is not iterable
```

---

At this point I'm a bit stumped, so if anybody could offer some insight as to what I should do to resolve the error and/or if I'm headed in the right direction code-wise I'd greatly appreciate it! *Sorry if the code doesn't make any sense I'll post the whole .py file if needed*

Comment: The second for loop makes no sense. It appears what you want to do is `concatenate_audioclips(songList)` without know anything about `moviepy` api.

Comment: @kesh Yes, that is what I'm trying to do, but when I try using songList as an argument I get an error saying that obj 'str' has no attribute 'duration'. I've poured over the moviepy api but it mostly only talks about compiling videos, there's very little to no info on concatenating audio or afx. I'm not even sure if there actually is a method called *concatenate_audioclips()*. And yes, I thought the second for loop was redundant but I've already tried *audio_clips = [AudioFileClip(c) for c in os.listdir(songDirectory)]*

Comment: Oh I see your error. `songList.append(filename)` should read `songList.append(audioclip)`. No wonder it complains that `str` doesn't have `duration`. Last, imho, it's sometimes easier to clone an open-source project that you are using and scan the code to better understand what's going on.

Comment: Ah yes, that worked. No idea why I hadn't considered that... Thanks a lot fr!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment by @kesh, you need to replace

```
songList.append(filename)
```

with

```
songList.append(audioclip)
```